# Sequelize: Query Returns String Array as String, Not as Array of Strings?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a Postgres table with a field in it named `specialties`. The field is defined as:

```
const myModel = db.define('my_model', {
    id: {type: Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true},
    createdAt: {type: Sequelize.DATE},
    updatedAt: {type: Sequelize.DATE},
    jobName: {type: Sequelize.STRING},
    specialties: {type: Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.STRING)}
});
```

I have populated the contents of the `specialties` field by importing a .csv file with strings in the following format:

```
["mySpeciality_1", "mySpeciality_2", "mySpeciality_3"]
```

I'm querying the table like so:

```
return Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => {
        let specialties = connectors.myModel.findAll({
            where: {'jobName': jobName}
        }).then((specialties) => specialties.map((item) => item.dataValues));
        return specialties;
    })
    .then(([specialties, metaData]) => {
        [.....]
```

`specialties` comes back as an object with a field named `specialties` that contains a string that looks like:

```
["mySpeciality_1", "mySpeciality_2", "mySpeciality_3"]
```

Did I import the string array field `specialties` with strings in the wrong format? Alternatively, do I need to write the sequelize query differently?

Comment: Are your backticks purposeful for template literals (are the square-brackets part of the string)?

Comment: 1) The backticks are only there for purposes of formatting on SO. Should there be backticks in the .csv? 2) The square-brackets are not part of the string -- it's just an attempt at some sort of syntax so that the postgres string array field will understand they are individual elements in the string array.

Comment: ...I guess since the text is indented, the backticks aren't needed.

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

First of all, I was defining the field as character varying[]. That doesn't seem to work. It seems to want to be text[]. Here's what it looks like in the Valentina postgres client:

[image]

I imported the fields from .csv in this format:

```
 {mySpeciality_1, mySpeciality_2, mySpeciality_3}
```

Here's the working sequelize query:

```
return Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => {
        let theJob = connectors.myModel.findAll({
            where: {'jobName': jobName}
        }).then((theJob) => theJob.map((item) => item.dataValues));
        return theJob;
    })
    .then(([theJob, metaData]) => {
        let specialties = theJob.specialties;
```